# What would be involved in moving a site like stackoverflow to https?

Tags: ssl, web-server

I've seen a lot of requests in the SO Meta asking for StackOverflow to be moved over completely to https.

I've never run a site as large as Stack Overflow, so enabling SSL/TLS has always just meant providing the cert files in the Apache/Nginx config.

How would this be different for a larger site such that it would require a significant amount of time to implement?

Comment: Have a look at this blog post by Nick Craver, http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/

Comment: Updated Nick Craver post on that topic; _highly_ recommended reading. https://nickcraver.com/blog/2017/05/22/https-on-stack-overflow/

Answer (score -2):

1) All absolute links should be changed to relative, or to ://, or to https://
For example: "http://mysite/img1.png" => "/img1.png" or "https://mysite/img1.png" or "://mysite/img1.png"

2) All links (css, js, fonts, frames) to external resources should be replaced to :// or to https://

All modern browsers are ignoring insecure http:// links from https pages!